# Grid versus GraphicsGrid use cases?

Tags: graphics

It seems that both `Grid` and `GraphicsGrid` can display graphics.  Following the documentation here `tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumns#391204127`, and avoiding screen shots, if

```
g$={{Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}], ImageSize -> 20], Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}], ImageSize -> 20]}, 
    {Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}], ImageSize -> 20], Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}], ImageSize -> 20]}}
```

then `Grid[g$]` and `GraphicsGrid[g$]` produce similar-looking output in a notebook, the only evident difference being padding.  Are there other non-obvious differences?  Any use-case advice, as in when to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GraphicsGrid` produces a `Graphics` object, which could be placed within another graphic or otherwise treated as a Graphics object, such as scaling, rotating, etc.  You can also, for instance, determine `ImageDimensions[GraphicsGrid[...]]`.  `Grid` does not produce a graphics object; `ImageDimensions[Grid[...]]` yields an error.  And so forth.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your answer when writing mine, but is the same.

Answer (score 5):

uuhahh, there is an important big difference.

Grid returns a Grid object whereas GraphicsGrid returns an Image. Therefore you will be able to apply all Image functions to  GraphicsGrid as a whole, whereas this is not possible on a Grid as a whole. 
Here an example to illustrate, try to use ImageRotate in both cases and see what is happening  :

Case 1:

```
ImageRotate[GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Disk[]]}, 
   {Graphics[Disk[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]]}}],90]
```

Case 2:

```
  ImageRotate[Grid[{{Graphics[Rectangle[]], Graphics[Disk[]]}, 
       {Graphics[Disk[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]]}}],90]
```

with following error for case 2:

ImageRotate::imginv: 
(("\"Expecting an image or graphics instead of ....

HINT: use //InputForm for analyzing and to get better understanding of high level  expressions